# Could neutrinos be tiny black holes?

Tags: particle-physics, black-holes, standard-model, neutrinos

I think about this because neutrinos only interact with gravity.

The Schwarzschild radius  is directly proportional to the mass and does not prevent values that tend to zero. There seems to be no minimum limit for the value of this radius.

If there is a limit, then I ask:

What is the minimum limit for the Schwarzschild radius to describe a real black hole?

Comment: Neutrinos participate in the weak interaction as well.

Comment: There is a well established and fairly well supported theory of how a low-mass black hole would behave. Have you done any research into the matter?

Comment: *I think about this because neutrinos only interact with gravity*. Those are sterile neutrinos.

Comment: We don't really have a theory that can deal with gravity in such an extreme way at a quantum level.  I think the fairest thing we can say is that this idea is not mainstream physics.

Answer (score 2):

No they couldn't. Their mass is so small that they would instantly evaporate due to [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation).

Comment: You're assuming Hawking's treatment remains valid for such light objects. That's a bold assumption.

Comment: The conditions in the early universe are not thought to have been able to form any https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primordial_black_hole